# PHP Commenting giving an error

Tags: php

I am running a php file with the below comments in the file.

```
 /* U can define as like C define */
 /* By default, name will be case sensitive, to make the name as case- insensitive add true 
    define ( "SERVER" , "localhost",true  );  /* Here server and SERVER will print local host */
  */
echo " Creating database file is executed second ";
```

with out the above comment, echo print is reflected whereas with the comments am getting nothing in the browser.

Could somebody please help me on this ?

Regards
Prasath S.

Comment: Look carefully. You have nested a comment within another comment. PHP doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

//  U can define as like C define 
 /* By default, name will be case sensitive, to make the name as case- insensitive add true 
    define ( "SERVER" , "localhost",true  );   Here server and SERVER will print local host 
  */
echo " Creating database file is executed second ";

?>
```

you cant put comment inside comment